# Magento 2 : Unable to generate Price for programmatically created 'custom product'

Tags: magento2, create-product

I have created a custom product for which I am able programmatically create products.

The problem is that i am unable to generate a price for these products. the field is left blank when the product is created.

This is how I create the product:

```
$_product = $this->productFactory->create();


            $_product->setName($array['ProductName']);
            $_product->setTypeId('Dome');
            $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $_product->setSku('test-SKU');
            $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
            $_product->setVisibility(4);
            $_product->setPrice(array(350));
            $_product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            $_product->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                    'qty' => 100 //qty
                    )
                );

            $product = $this->productRepository->save($_product);


            $id = $product->getId();

            return $id;
```

I have also tried this to no avail:

> $_product->setPrice(350);

This is how the custom product was created:

> product_types.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="Dome" label="Event Dome Product" modelInstance="Mymodule\Example\Model\Product\Type\EventDome"
          composite="false" isQty="true" canUseQtyDecimals="false" sortOrder="83">
        <priceModel instance="Mymodule\Example\Model\Product\Type\Price"/>
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
            <attribute name="taxable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code to add price like :

```
$_product->setPrice(350.00)
```

or try with below example :

```
$storeId = '1'; //Store ID
$product_id = 7878;
$price = "350.01";
$productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$product = $productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product_id);
$product->setPrice($price);
$product->save();
```

**hope its working for you**

Comment: hi. Thanks for replying. but it did not work

Comment: try with store id. or put the value - 350.01

Comment: how do you mean with store Id?

Comment: i update my answer with example please check.

Comment: $_product->setStoreId(1); add this line in your code.

Comment: it still does not work. i am totally baffled where i could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After this script:

```
        $_product = $this->productFactory->create();
        $_product->setName($array['ProductName']);
        $_product->setTypeId('Dome');
        $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $_product->setSku('test-SKU');
        $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $_product->setVisibility(4);
        $_product->setPrice(array(350));
        $_product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $_product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => 100 //qty
                )
            );

        $product = $this->productRepository->save($_product);


        $id = $product->getId();
```

** Try This **

```
//Now Load product model and save price

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();<br/>
$productObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);<br/>
$productObj->setPrice(100)->save();
```

Comment: hi. i tried it. it does not work.

Comment: i think i know what is wrong. i did not put price within my attribue set for productsetup-installData. do you know how i can remove the previous attribute set and install a new one